# set & get checkbox from local storage

Tags: jquery

```js
$("input[name='application']").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem("APPLICATION", $(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center brdr">
    <h4>Application Type*</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 d-flex align-items-center col-lg-1 brdr">
    <input type="checkbox" name="application" class="check form-check-input me-2" required> New
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark d-flex align-items-center col-lg-2 brdr">
    <input type="checkbox" id="update" name="application" class="check form-check-input me-2" required> Update
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()">
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  const application = localStorage.getItem("APPLICATION");
  if (application !== null) {
    $("input[name='application']").attr("checked", "checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center brdr">
    <h4>Application Type*</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 d-flex align-items-center col-lg-1 brdr">
    <input type="checkbox" name="application" class="check form-check-input me-2" required> New
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark d-flex align-items-center col-lg-2 brdr">
    <input type="checkbox" id="update" name="application" class="check form-check-input me-2" required> Update
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a form where i want to get the value after submitting the form on the next page. so i tried to get this by local storage. i tried this code, but its not working.

Comment: How exactly is this _"not working"_? You have two checkboxes with `name="application"`, only one has an `id` and neither have a `value` (so `.val()` will only ever return _"on"_). You store values into `localStorage` but never clear them. How should the value stored influence the second page? What should happen? What does happen?

Comment: i want which checkbox is checked in first page it also selected in the next page

Answer (score 0):

1. Give both your checkboxes an `id` attribute so they can be identified
2. Add a *change* handler to add or remove the `id` value into storage
3. On your second page, read the values and check the matching elements

#### HTML for both pages

```html
<input
  id="application-new"
  type="checkbox"
  name="application"
  class="check form-check-input me-2"
/> New

<input
  id="application-update"
  type="checkbox"
  name="application"
  class="check form-check-input me-2"
/> Update
```

#### First page JS

```js
// Store the set of IDs in a variable
const applicationChecks = new Set();

$(document.body).on("change", "input[name=application][id]", (e) => {
  const {
    target: { id, checked },
  } = e;

  // if checked, add the id, otherwise remove it
  applicationChecks[checked ? "add" : "delete"](id);

  // write to localStorage as an array
  localStorage.setItem("APPLICATION", JSON.stringify([...applicationChecks]));
});
```

#### Second page JS

```js
jQuery(($) => {
  // load the id array from localStorage
  const applicationChecks =
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("APPLICATION")) ?? [];

  // for each id, find the element and set its `checked` property
  $(applicationChecks.map((id) => `#${id}`).join(", ")).prop("checked", true);
});
```

[image: Edit cold-shape-7huzm3]

Comment: its not working

Comment: @Azhar I've added a sandbox link so you can see it working. If it's not working for you then you must have missed something. _"It's not working"_ tells me absolutely nothing

Comment: i just copied your code then how i can miss something